# PHP Websockets (Ratchet) with including files

Tags: php, websocket, localhost

I am trying to implement websockets for an application that I am working on. I am using Ratchet to do so and I am having problems including files (such as database connection files, user files, etc.

I keep getting the following error

***Warning: include(): Failed opening '../includes/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.4/share/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bidzwon/app/Socket.php on line 28***

Again, I am new to this technology and could use any help, thanks

Comment: Check if '../includes/connect.php' exists and is accessible by your script.